# How to connect HP6700 wireless printer to Elementary Loki

Tags: networking, printer

I have a HP6700 wireless network printer and want to connect my elementary laptop using the wireless connection but have not found a way to do this.  Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score -2):

Switch OS. It's almost impossible to make a printer work in E-OS unless you are very lucky (or that you managed to endure this Apple travestite long enough that you grew accustomed with complicated steps that leads more than not to total waste of time). As you can see I'm having fun *trying* to install (for the X time) a printer in the same OS.

Welcome to Linux!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to comment on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) from the asker. | >> [Help Center](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help) <<